# Return array key via array value in multiple array data

Tags: php, arrays

My `$_SESSION` stores array in the format below. All of `productId` value are unique. I want to get array key using a `productId`.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [productId] => 3
        [productQuantity] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [productId] => 4
        [productQuantity] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [productId] => 5
        [productQuantity] => 1
    )

)
```

I have tried `array_search` but its not working. I actually saw a similar question, but the answer was left untold. This is the code i tried but its not displaying anything:

```
$key = array_search(3,$_SESSION['cart']);
echo $key;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they are unique just re-index by the `productId`:

```
$cart = array_column($_SESSION['cart'], null, 'productId');
echo $cart[3]['productQuantity'];
```

Or:

```
echo array_column($_SESSION['cart'], null, 'productId')[3]['productQuantity'];
```

If you'll only ever have those 2 then it makes sense to extract `productQuantity` and re-index by `productId`:

```
$cart = array_column($_SESSION['cart'], 'productQuantity', 'productId');
echo $cart[3];
```

The array will look like `$cart = [3 => 1, 4 => 1, 5 => 1]`.

Or:

```
echo array_column($_SESSION['cart'], 'productQuantity', 'productId')[3];
```

If you really just want the current key for some reason, extract `productId` and search that (as long as keys are 0 based and sequential:

```
$key = array_search(3, array_column($_SESSION['cart'], 'productId'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, but this did not actually work. 1 only want to get the key of the array by the productId. like productId 3 has the key 0, productId 4 has the key 1. When i supply the productId, it should give me only the key associated to that productId.

Comment: I understand that but why?  What is the end goal to getting the key?

Comment: i want to update productQuantity value using the key

Comment: I edited, but it would be much easier to use the `productId` as the key wouldn't it???  Yes, it would.

Comment: Yes I caught that.  Still, take some seasoned advice as use id as the key.